# Margin not working

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with margin on my site: [link](http://www.odsavacky.cz/produkty) , when i want increase space between left_sidebar and right_content with margin then there is no change.

CSS{

```
.left_sidebar{
    float: left;
    padding: 30px 0;
    width: 28.2%;
    margin-right: 20px !important;
}


.content_right {
    float: right;
    padding: 30px 0;
    width: 69%;
}
```

Comment: I would highly recommend looking into Boostrap, it makes what you are trying to achieve very simple: http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are floating left and right while using percentage widths. This doesn't leave any room for margin. There are different ways to fix this, but I would suggest decreasing the percentage of both divs to allow more room between them.